# Посмотрите на код, можно ли написать по-другому

Tags: python

Кубик с цифрами от 1 до 6 подбрасывают пять раз. Составьте программу вычисления среднего значения этих чисел с использованием функции с параметрами.Напишите пожалуйста код, более легче если можете.Можно ли написать его в одну строку? Заранее спасибо.

```
import random
def func(s):
    x=random.randint(1,7)
    print(i+1," выпал число: ",x)
    s=s+x
    return (s)
s=0
for i in range(6):
    s=func(s)
print("сумма очков:  ",s)
print("средний арифмет:  ",s/6)`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Параметром сделал количество бросков.

```
from random import randint
def result(n):
    return sum([randint(1,6) for _ in range(n)])/n
print(result(5))
```

объявили функцию result с параметром n - количество бросков.

```
def result(n):
```

с помощь генератора списка ([List comprehension](https://pythonru.com/osnovy/python-list-comprehension)) создаем список с результатами бросков:

```
[randint(1,6) for _ in range(n)]
```

для понимания, генератор списка можно переписать простым циклом:

```
res = []
for _ in range(n):
    res.append(randint(1,6))
```

нижнее подчеркивание _ в цикле означает что у нас не будет переменной в которую обычно записывается индекс, но он нам здесь и не нужен

затем суммируем результаты бросков встроенной функцией **sum** и делим на количество бросков **n**

---

или через lambda-у

```
from random import randint
result = lambda n: sum([randint(1,6) for _ in range(n)])/n
print(result(5))
```

Comment: Надо конкретным параметром. Но спасибо что помогли.

Comment: а какой именно?

Comment: Прошу прошения  за невнимательный, нет конкретного параметра всё Вы правильно сделали. Благодарю Вас за помощь.

Comment: Но если Вам не тяжело, можете объяснить код?

Comment: @Solomon дописал